# Colorize Bubbles based on a value in a ggplot country map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a complete R newbie but based on this nice and precious article (https://medium.com/@juliabelkin/step-by-step-map-plotting-with-r-ggplot2-4e4de3cf2190) I was able to create a map with bubbles. The bubble size reflects a value.

However, **I fail to also colorize the circles based on the values.** Any ideas?

```
// R-file
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(mapproj)

name <- c("Berlin", "München", "Hamburg", "Bremen", "Köln", "Leipzig", "Frankfurt", "Dresden", "Hannover", "Dortmund")
lat <- c(52.5234299, 48.1391258, 53.5572548, 53.0749817, 50.9405327, 51.3396912, 50.1108856, 51.0509911, 52.3720665, 51.5110321)
long <- c(13.4114361, 11.5802193, 9.995966, 8.8070812, 6.9599056, 12.371356, 8.679492, 13.733633, 9.7356863, 7.4635186)
value <- c(350000, 250000, 80000, 70000, 70000, 70000, 50000, 40000, 35000, 35000)
data <- data_frame(name, lat, long, value)

Germany <- map_data("world") %>% filter(region=="Germany")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = Germany, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill="deepskyblue", alpha=0.7) +
  geom_point( data=data, aes(x=long, y=lat, size=value,),  color="mediumblue",  alpha=0.5) +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(5, 30)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank())
```

Used software:

- R version 4.3.2
- Version 2023.12.0+369 (2023.12.0+369)
- macOS 14.2.1 (Sonoma) on a M1 Mac

[image: R plotted Map with Bubbles]

Comment: Is there a column in your data frame that has values that you want to tie to the colors of the bubbles? If not, please describe how you want the bubbles colored. If so, you need to include `color = name_of_that_column` inside `aes()` in your `geom_point()` layer, and delete `color="mediumblue"`. If it's the `value` column, then change `size=value,` to `size = value, color = value` and delete `color="mediumblue"`.

Comment: Thank you! But where and how can I define the color-range between min and max value?

Comment: Add `scale_color_gradient()` to your plot and see the `?scale_color_gradient` help page for examples.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas That helped a lot. Unfortunately someone flagged my question as a duplicate and closed it, so I am not able to accept your answer.

Comment: These are just comments, not answers. I flagged your question as a duplicate and closed it. If you read the thorough answers at the marked duplicate, you'll learn quite a bit about color scales in ggplot!